# How to register some answers into the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a test. The respondents are gonna get a video and some radio buttons to pick the right answer. When i answer the first question i get back to it until i refresh the page then i move to the next question (but the answer for the second question pick as the same answer for the first one :/)

I have `qid` as question ID, `rid` as respondent ID, `pid` as project ID cuz i each project has different questions.

How can i save the answers in the database and move to the next one directly?

```
$ridsession= $_SESSION['rid'];
$pidsession= $_SESSION['pid'];  

$sql = "SELECT coalesce(max(qid)+1,1) AS id FROM result  WHERE rid=".$ridsession." AND pid =". $pidsession;

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

        $qid=$row['id'];
    }
}   

echo "<form  id='radioform' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='radioform'>";

$sql2= "SELECT pid, qid, question_link FROM question WHERE pid=".$pidsession." AND qid=".$qid;

$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result2->fetch_array()) {

    echo $row['question_link']."<br>";
    }
}   

$sql3= "SELECT pid, qid, aid, answer, points FROM answer_det WHERE pid=".$pidsession." AND qid=".$qid;

$result3 = $mysqli->query($sql3);

if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result3->fetch_array()) {
        $answer= $row['answer'];
        $aid= $row['aid'];

    echo "<input type='radio' name='answer' value='".$aid."'/>".$aid.". ".$answer."<br>";
    }
}

echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Nästa' onclick='return Validation()'></form>";

$answers = $_POST['answer'];

$sql2= "SELECT pid, qid, aid, answer, points FROM answer_det WHERE pid=".$pidsession." AND qid=".$qid." AND aid=".$answers;
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result2->fetch_array()) {
        $points = $row['points'];
    }
}

$q = "INSERT INTO result VALUES($ridsession,$pidsession,$qid,$answers, $points)";
$r = mysqli_query($mysqli,$q);
```

Comment: seeing your many related questions, this seems to be an incremental build/question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i'm a student not a professional programmer, i'm working on my homework, i'm learning how to make stuff, so..

Comment: This particular project seems to be cropping up quite a lot over the last week or so. I hope that your lecturer is monitoring SO to find out which of their student need some extra tutorials.